# @Value returning the property name instead of value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, properties

I have a `Controller` like this:

```
public class Controller extends AbstractController {
    ...

    @Value("${application.property.list}")
    private Set<String> properties;

    ...

}
```

And the `application.properties` looks like this:

```
application.property.list = property1,property2,property3,property4
```

Why the field `properties` contains the property name `"application.property.list"` instead of the values?

However, if i create a separated `@Component` like this one:

```
@Component
public class AvailableProperties {

    private final Set<String> values;

    @Autowired
    private AvailableProperties(@Value("${application.property.list}") final Set<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Set<String> values() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(values);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly by injecting it in the `Controller`

```
@Autowired
private AvailableProperties availableProperties;
```